# How to export an sqlite database as queries

Tags: sqlite

I have created and populated a database using SQLite Toolbox for Visual Studio but find it improper to commit a binary to my CVS.. I was thinking about exporting it as queries that I can then run to create the database with the data.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to achieve this from SQLite Toolbox but maybe there some functionality directly from SQLite or another tool I can use for this ?

Comment: `sqlite3 yours.db .dump > queries.sql` will generate queries.sql with your queries. then it can restore also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export database as queries in **sqlite3** using

```
 sqlite3 your_database.db .dump > queries.sql
```

This `queries.sql` file can use for database restore.

**To restore**

```
sqlite3 new_database.db < queries.sql
```

which will create `new_database.db`